# FuelPHP ORM Issues - Magic methods are called even though they shouldn't

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp

First of all, let me say that the following situation does not happen all the time, but maybe once or twice per day (and sometimes not even once a day). Also, it happens only on production. So it's really hard for me to do proper debugging, and all I could was to capture the backtrace and write it down in the logs.

I have an ORM model, that extends `\Orm\Model`. I'm using `Model_X::find()` to get the needed objects. But, in the constructor of that model, strange things start happening:

The first line of the constructor is

```
if( ! empty($this->_data))
```

This triggers magic `__isset('_data')`, which then calls magic `__get('_custom_data')`, from this line:

```
elseif (array_key_exists($property, $this->_custom_data))
```

And this goes on, until eventually the an exception is thrown:

```
Undefined property: Model_X::$_view
```

from this line:

```
elseif ($this->_view and in_array($property, static::$_views_cached[get_class($this)][$this->_view]['columns']))
```

What's odd here is that all these properties _data, _view, _custom_data are defined in `\Orm\Model` class. And my understanding is that **if the property is defined, there is no need to call __get, since "The overloading methods are invoked when interacting with properties or methods that have not been declared or are not visible in the current scope"**

My question is: Why does empty($this->_data) calls for __isset (and that triggers all the subsequent calls), when in fact, that property is defined for this class?

This is a relevant part of the backtrace:

```
"file": "/fuel/packages/orm/classes/model.php",
"line": 1028,
"function": "{closure}",
"args": [8, "Undefined property: Model_Supplier::$_view", "/fuel/packages/orm/classes/model.php", 1028, {
    "property": "_view",
    "rel": false,
    "this": {},
    "value": false

"file": "/fuel/packages/orm/classes/model.php",
"line": 865,
"function": "get",
"class": "Orm\\Model",
"object": {},
"type": "->",
"args": ["_view"]

"file": "/fuel/packages/orm/classes/model.php",
"line": 1028,
"function": "__get",
"class": "Orm\\Model",
"object": {},
"type": "->",
"args": ["_view"]

"file": "/fuel/packages/orm/classes/model.php",
"line": 865,
"function": "get",
"class": "Orm\\Model",
"object": {},
"type": "->",
"args": ["_custom_data"]

"file": "/fuel/packages/orm/classes/model.php",
"line": 899,
"function": "__get",
"class": "Orm\\Model",
"object": {},
"type": "->",
"args": ["_custom_data"]

"file": "/fuel/packages/orm/classes/model.php",
"line": 730,
"function": "__isset",
"class": "Orm\\Model",
"object": {},
"type": "->",
"args": ["_data"]

"file": "/fuel/packages/orm/classes/model.php",
"line": 124,
"function": "__construct",
"class": "Orm\\Model",
"object": {},
"type": "->",
```

*Edit*: I've actually resolved this (I think). Since the error goes away after php-fpm restart, my idea was this - cache gets corrupted, after the restart corrupted cache gets cleaned up. The only cache going on is APC, so I went and disabled it.

Comment: Very good question, in my almost 3 years of FuelPHP I have never seen this. As you correctly stated, it is defined in the parent model, and should therefore not trigger a magic method. 
Just a thought, you're not doing an unset somewhere?

Comment: No I'm not. Here is something else weird: when I dump $this in the constructor, I get all properties in the dump. When I dump $this in the __isset method, I get empty object (it is Model_X type of object, but all properties are gone). Also if I dump $this->_data as a first statement in the constructor, I get empty array (which is fine).

Comment: There must be something that triggers this, properties don't tend to magically disappear. Nothing special in your model? No _init() that could ruin things?

Comment: I forgot to update this. I've actually disabled APC and the issue went away.